# NSTableView Delete Row by clearing text

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I want a simple table with 1 string column that adds a new line by using the return key. 
Also I want to delete a row if the user clears the text on a particular row too.

I've managed to add a new line with return key with this method:

```
-(BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector{
if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {
    [self returnKey];
    return YES;
}
else if(commandSelector == @selector(moveUp:)){
    [self tableMoveUp];
    return YES;
}
else if(commandSelector == @selector(moveDown:)){
    [self tableMoveDown];
    return YES;
}
else{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(commandSelector));
}

return NO;
```

}

The problem is deleting a row when the user clears the text on a row and hits the return key. This method is being called before the actual changes on the table get saved to the data source. I've tried getting the dataCell on the column like this:

```
NSTextFieldCell *cell = [self.tableView.tableColumns[0] dataCell];
NSLog(@"%@",cell.stringValue);
```

But the stringValue is not accurate.
Any ideas on how to achieve this ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since a table column's data cell is reused for each row (set its value and "stamp" it in place when drawing, lather, rinse, repeat), this is an odd place to put this kind of code. The "stringValue is not accurate" observation is a big clue to this - it'll be set to whatever value the cell was last used to draw, which can't and shouldn't be determined.

Why not have the data source manage it? When -tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row: is called, check if obj is empty string / nil / whatever, then remove that row and reload. "Empty this cell" is a user action; the table view handles it and lets its data source (a controller) know when the user committed to the change.

If you want to have "delete/backspace deletes the row" then customize NSTextFieldCell to send up a "MyTableRowWasDeleted" notification, which your data source can observe and take appropriate steps to end editing and remove the "empty" row, then reload.